# How to detect a region around a point

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

In my Winforms application, I am painting 2D shapes.

Where i click, I want to fill the surrounding shape (or region in case of intersection of shapes). How can I get the region surrounding a point?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can compose a region from a set of 'shapes', lines, points or rectangles.

Comment: @leppie : i have the point only,how to get region around it ??

Comment: Check this for intersection with polygons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test. For finding shapes around the point, you can simply find all shapes which points or origin are within a specific distance from your point